# Is there a way to make Windows always start browsing for files starting from the current directory?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Question should be straightforward enough.
I'm sure every Windows user has had it, is there a way to make Windows always start browsing starting from the current directory, be that using either windows explorer or any other program?

Maybe there is a registry setting that accounts for these, or is it setup per program? Or there is some 3d party program that does this? I am on Windows 8.1 amd64. If anybody knows kindly share.

Comment: What is your definition of "current directory"?

Comment: Start browsing *what* from the current directory? So you go somewhere in Explorer, you have effectively "browsed" to a location, so what exactly are you expecting to browse? What do you expect to achieve? I feel like there is something missing here.

Comment: *"Is there a way to make Windows always start browsing starting from the current directory, be that using either windows explorer or any other program?"* - You mean from something like a file selection dialog?

Comment: I mean when the explorer dialog opens up prompting you to browse for a file and select it. If a current directory exists it will be the directory where you have opened the current file.

Comment: Your question is like a paradox and falls on upon it. Explorer.exe is always present and running in Windows, so that means even if you're in desktop than still you are browsing your user profile's Desktop folder. And whenever you open explorer in a directory that is **current directory**.

Comment: @WasifHasan You did not understand the question.

Comment: @Nikos - You should edit your question and clarify it.  You have significantly over estimated the clarity of you question.